# css text and resize/shrink big image to fit A4 - increase DPI

Tags: css, image, screen, dpi

how to solve the issue of mixing text with high resolution images?
For instance, an image of 4Mpix(or more), displayed in browser with screen of 1024x768 or Full HD and you don't want to scroll horizontaly, also on A4 print, you don't want the image to be chopped.

Thanks?

```
A4 is 210mm × 297mm
72 dpi (web) = 595 X 842 pixels 
300 dpi (print) = 2480 X 3508 pixels
600 dpi (print) = 4960 X 7016 pixels
```

The best I found was something as such, but on Full HD screen it's stupid and it does not offer good DPI at print.

```
<STYLE type="text/css">
img {
max-width:800px;
max-height:800px;
}
</STYLE>
```

Also tried

```
<STYLE type="text/css">
body{
width: 21cm;
padding: 2cm;
margin: 1cm auto; }
</STYLE>
```

html code of page might be

```
<body>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p><img src="3200by1800image.JPG"></p>
<p>other image</p>
<p><img src="600by400image.JPG"></p>
</body>
```

P.S. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/high-dpi/

Answer (score 0):

Using the percentages instead of fixed amounts can help.
e.g.

```
width:50%
height:50%
```

You could also use media-queries to replace the picture with a higher resolution picture on a bigger screen?

This can be done like this:
HTML

```
<img src="mobile.jpg" data-src-desktop="desktop.jpg" alt="">
```

CSS

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    img[data-src-desktop] {
        content: attr(data-src-desktop, url);
    }
}
```